# Windows 10 Notepad can't find text

Tags: windows, search, notepad

When I paste this into Notepad on Windows 10:

```
"first_name"=>"M", "surname"=>"C", "country"=>"Australia"
```

and then try to find the string "name" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, it comes up blank:

[image: Notepad find]

Is Notepad's Find function completely useless or am I missing something?

Comment: I advise Wordpad instead. Not sure if it's part of Base Windows though.

Comment: @Malandy +1 to Wordpad for being better than Notepad. If by "base Windows" you mean it is installed automatically, then yes, it comes with base Windows.

Comment: @MindS1 - Yeah, that's what I meant. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: @Malandy as far as built-in Windows utilities go, Wordpad is the best you can get. The best alternatives are Notepad++ for general use, Sublime Text if you're a programmer, or VIM if you're a baller power user.

Comment: I think if you open up a file that has null characters between each byte of ASCII (e.g. `T\x00E\x00X\x00T\x00`, which might happen if a UTF-16 file isn't detected as such), it can also cause strange things to happen, where you'll just see `TEXT` as the nulls get hidden, but never find `TEXT` in it. That behavior may have changed in newer Windows versions though.

Comment: .reg files on at least some windows versions are notorious for that - they are UTF16 and confuse many editors....

Comment: The *real* answer is to use Notepad++ instead.

Comment: I always get surprised that when people are not using Notepad++. Sure, 1995 was a good time but it has passed.

Comment: I do not consider Notepad to be completely useless. There are many many regular users who are not developers. They do not need all fancy features of `notepad++` or don't care about those. They may use Notepad to jot down few notes here and there. I understand that Notepad is severely `crippled` for any serious developmental work, but it is not completely throw-away either.

Comment: @Pikamander2 The _real real_ answer is to use Vim instead. ;)

Comment: @MindS1 in all seriousness I recommend using gVim on Windows until the [DOS prompt colours](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/) and Vim work together fully. Also gVim is much more tolerant for Windows users. The Windows team have made massive steps in the DOS prompt in Windows 10 to make it capable of fully supporting things like Vim. Also it's worth noting that anyone who's installed Git will have Vim included in the user binaries that come with it. Having syntax highlighting inside Vim on the DOS prompt is really quite trippy.

Comment: For goodness sake, Notepad itself is useless. Please use a modern text editor instead of purposely shooting yourself in the face.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The Find function starts where you placed your cursor. Since you pasted into Notepad, the cursor is likely at the end of the document.

You can either

1. move the cursor to the beginning of the document
2. switch the Find direction from Down to Up

Comment: Hint: To move the caret to the start of the file, press Ctrl+Home. (Also, a bit of nitpicking: in Windows, you typically use "cursor" for the mouse pointer thing and "caret" for the text input thing.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand only you use that probably, I've never heard anyone actually say caret... or maybe we're both showing our age!

Comment: Caret is correct, but it's a bit like talking about Kibibytes. It causes more confusion than benefit in most cases.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Microsoft use the terms cursor and pointer for text cursor and mouse cursor, respectively. "Caret" is only used to describe the text cursor in Windows when talking about "caret browsing" (a term introduced by Firefox). Otherwise it's the ^ symbol/diacritic.

Comment: Text cursor is referenced almost exclusively as "caret" in Windows API documentation. The `SetCursorPos` function moves the mouse pointer (cursor) to given (screen) position. The `SetCaretPos` places the text cursor at given position relative to window's client area.

Comment: Microsoft obviously regularly participates and wins in contests where the most counter-intuitive UI behaviours are awarded.

Comment: How about "Keyboard cursor"?

Comment: Just say 'caret'. Why contribute further to the dumbing-down of society? If somebody doesn't know what it is, then they will learn something. Great!

Comment: Click to relocate is the "scalpel" solution. Closing and re-opening the file is the "axe". Windows keyboards have a home key as well.  Why is the flashing cursor not obvious? It needs to be a block or thick underscore ala VT100/220.

Comment: Oh wait, you guys are talking about the insertion point.

Comment: @codah because caret is not the correct word. It's similar - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/caret is a mark to indicate a proposed insertion in a text - but not the same. There you go, you've learnt something. Great!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)#Text_cursor

Comment: Wow. I really touched a nerve with this question :)

Comment: @allo Especially since we usually mean the caret-character `^` when talking about carets.

Comment: Warning: Notepad remembers the search direction across restart. I once set the direction to Up, then several days later I started Notepad and it wouldn't find anything (because it was searching up from the beginning of the document).

Answer (score 59):

Notepad doesn't support wrap-around search. If you select search direction as *Down* then it only searches from the cursor *onward*. Similarly *Up* will only search *backward*. The workaround is already mentioned in Worthwelle's answer

However since [build 17666](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/07/11/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17713/#43xOZoKdjhoIaSgf.97) Notepad will be able to do wrap-around search and you don't need to mess with that Up/Down options. That'll likely enter the main branch on [Windows 10 version 1809](https://howtofixwindows.com/notepad-improvements-windows-10-version-1809/)

> **Wrap-around find/replace:** We’ve made significant improvement to the find/replace experience in Notepad. We added the option to do wrap-around find/replace to the find dialog and Notepad will now remember previously entered values and the state of checkboxes and automatically populate them the next time you open the find dialog. Additionally, when you have text selected and open the find dialog we will automatically populate the search field with the selected text.
>
> [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17713](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/07/11/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17713/#43xOZoKdjhoIaSgf.97)

[image: Notepad wrap around search]

Comment: :o they're making notepad useful? What next - hex editor? regex? Why not just toss it out and put VSCode in instead.. :)

Comment: @CaiusJard: Same reason why ed, not emacs, is the standard Unix text editor. >_>

Comment: @CaiusJard why would anyone who doesn't do coding need VS code? At least MS made Notepad understand *nix line endings for WSL to work, and while taking the chance to fix that why don't just do other improvements as well?

Comment: @CaiusJard they used to have a sort-of hex editor, good ol' MS-DOS debug (think it might still exist in 32-bit Windows) :-)

Comment: @phuclv it was a bit of a tongue-in-cheek comment from me initially, but the essence of it was; they have at least one really smart, powerful text editor, and after about 20 years of dev notepad is getting the most basic of features to improve its usability - if they carry on in this way, in about 150 years or so, notepad will be vscode, so why not just drop notepad and use some (hollowed out, if you insist) vscode right now..

Comment: A notepad instance uses 2 MB of RAM and starts instantly.  VS Code... doesn't.

Comment: I can imagine the excitement of the developer who was tasked with adding these amazing features to Notepad.

Comment: @codah I don't know if "excitement" is the right word for adding features to a piece of software that's probably older than the developer themselves.

Comment: @JustinLardinois turn on your sarcasm detector :)

Comment: @codah [Maintaining Notepad is not a full-time job, but it’s not an empty job either](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180521-00/?p=98795)

Comment: @CaiusJard the reason it's not going to get all those features is because it's supposed to remain a bare bones text editor, it's not meant to be an IDE.

Comment: ["Today, we’re excited to announce that we have fixed this issue!"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/). The future is now.

Comment: *:o they're making notepad useful?* 
Caius Jard, don't get too excited.
Microsoft still makes sure that the *default* EOL is CRLF.
With no option for us, the users – their paying customers – to ever change the default EOL to LF.
I don't expect any change in that respect in the nearest decade.
Counting down till 2033 …
On second thought, make that TWO decades. See you in 2043! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Notepad's "find" feature searches either forward or backwards using the cursor's current position as a reference point.

You can see the radio buttons "Up" and "Down" for search direction. "Down" searches for the next match after the cursor, and "Up" searches for the previous match before the cursor. As you search, it moves the cursor around so that it doesn't find the same text over and over again.

The search doesn't wrap around when you hit the end of a document (unlike many other text editing programs).

You can either move the cursor to the beginning of the document, or you can change the radio button to "Up" to search in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

As many have pointed out the reason is cursor is at the end, and it does not support wrap around. What has not been mentioned yet rather than trying both up and down direction searches (Say you were in middle, you would need to try both) you can simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, since all are highlighted it will search everything.

Comment: It's better to use Ctrl+Home since nothing will be selected and you won't accidentally delete the content by pressing some key

Answer (score -1):

> Is Notepad's "Find" function completely useless or am I missing something?

Notepad is basically useless.  I only use it when I am writing short batch files (because `cmd.exe` doesn't like UNIX line endings) or need a very quick scratch pad to jot some brief notes that I don't mind losing in the event of a power outage.  Notepad is very light on system resources and has the fastest startup time of any Windows text editor I've ever used but that's probably *because* it is near useless.  WordPad, which also comes with Windows, is even more useless as a text editor for a variety of reasons - unless you need to create RTF files for some odd purpose.

When you need to find text in a text file on Windows, I recommend installing and using a real text editor.  I still use Crimson Editor (the 2004 version, not the mostly broken Emerald Editor version).  It's a really good editor as long as you don't need non-ASCII character encodings - it'll do UTF-8 but only if you coax it - and, IMO, beats Notepad++ on all the core areas of text editing that matter even though it is pretty old software at this point.  Crimson also handles loading 200MB+ log files pretty well - most editors choke after 30-50MB.  UltraEdit and Vim are the only other two text editors out there that can handle extremely large text files (not that you asked).  I can't stand Notepad++, VS Code, and most text editors but Crimson's not for everyone either.  Notepad++ Portable can be used on (most) machines that don't allow installing software on them.

My recommendation is to try a few different text editors to find one you like - just search for "alternative to [name of text editor]" on Google to start finding hundreds of options.  Quite a few are free and pretty much any text editor is vastly superior to Notepad except for the few that come with obvious malware.

If you need to find specific text across multiple files on Windows, I recommend the `findstr` command from a Command Prompt:

```
cd path\to\files
findstr /sic:"what you want to find" *
```

It's WAY faster than any other method of finding things via Windows Explorer.

Comment: I use notepad as a staging area to wash RTF formatting, it cures a lot of evils. In ancient times Help/About would report installed memory.  It is still useful as a scratch pad when copying and pasting snippets of data that Notepad++ would need to be programmed to highlight.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Just looked up Crimson Editor (never heard of it before) and see that the latest version was released in... 2008. I doubt that it even has 64-bit version, and no Unicode support is a big no-no, most people live in countries where ASCII is not enough, and even if you're speaking English you'll still need symbols like →μ►™✔... in Unicode. `most editors choke after 30-50MB` most advanced editors I've used can handle a log file of hundreds of MBs or even GBs without problem. Probably you haven't updated for decades. And `findstr` isn't as good as `grep` if you want to do advanced searching

Comment: "find specific text across multiple files on Windows I recommend the `findstr`", I'd recommend installing `ripgrep`, you can get it from the [ripgrep Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ripgrep), it's built using Rust and can be ridiculously fast at searching through massive code bases.